# Clicking clock opens notifications not clock settings

Tags: macos, big-sur, desktop

Today I noticed that clicking on the time/date in the top-right of my screen displays the notifications panel, instead of the date settings as it has the last 5-10 years. I used this as recently as last week.

I just updated Big Sur last night to 11.6, is it possibly related?

### Got this

[image]

### Expected this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior in macOS Big Sur.  Apple introduced the new-to-Mac Notification Center which dramatically changed a lot of long-standing Mac conventions.

Comment: I've almost definitely been able to click on the clock since I get this machine a few weeks ago... it came with Big Sur pre-installed. Are you saying there's now no shortcut to the time settings?

Comment: @Mr.Boy correct